# How to perform Pub Get programatically from a Dart program

Tags: dart, installation, yaml, dart-pub

I'm building a Dart framework called Modular for backend development and this framework has a installer for convenience. At the end of the installation, I'd like to install all dependancies in the generated `pubspec.yaml` file. How would I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  Process.run('pub', ['get'], 
      runInShell: true, 
      workingDirectory: 'dirWherePubspec.yaml_is')
  .then((ProcessResult results) {
    // ...
  });
}
```

or alternatively `Process.start(...)`